# How can I see which files are opened by a command?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I know `lsof`, which shows me the files opened by a running process, but if I launch a command, like `calendar`, that terminates immediately.

How can I see what config files are read?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `strace -efile calendar` for this. The resulting output is a little hard to read, but it shows every file-related action, including failed attempts at opening files and uses of 'stat' to see if a file exists.

Answer (score 0):

I use `find -mmin -2` or `find -amin -2` to see which files were concerned by a command.

Comment: This only works if the `atime` is recorded, which is often not the case. Also, how exactly would you see which command opened a file returned by `find`?

Comment: It's a raw technique but I launch `find etc` before and after the command so I can see what change. I agree it's not precise but it often help.